# YUI App transition "flickers" on showView

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, yui

I have a problem with transitions in a YUI app. Every time I change view using the showView method, then the content of the view is move to left for a very short time and then back to where it belongs.

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/casperskovgaard/ez7wH/

I use this css to center the view:

```
#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}
```

If I remove css, then the view doesn't flicker... But I need it to be centered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of your js code, set `transitions` to `false`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/RmGJk/)

```
YUI().use('app', 'demo-app', function (Y) {
    'use strict';

    var demoApp = new Y.DemoApp({
        root: '/demo',
        serverRouting: false,
        transitions: false
    });

    demoApp.render();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that does fix the problem. But shouldn't it be possible to use transitions?

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard You either use transitions (and you'll obtain the flickr efect) or you don't use. Please note that you can use customized transitions (or other transitions defined within YUI3 lib). If the answer above helped you, please upvote & accept the answer :)

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard Look at this for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ez7wH/1/). Anyway, seems that routing on jsfiddle doesn't work that good. It shouldn't dispatch twice on the same route, from my knowledge.

Comment: @eAbi I do appreciate your answer, but it didn't really solved the transition problem. It just removed the transition. Looking at this example: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-contributors.html#/github/yui/ it should be possible to have a centered layout combined with transitions.